# ggplot not plotting linestring points from sf object

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

Given the following data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
df <- structure(list(geometry = c("LINESTRING (-85.76 38.34, -85.72 38.38)", 
                                  "LINESTRING (-85.46 38.76, -85.42 38.76)", 
                                  "LINESTRING (-85.89 38.31, -85.89 38.31)"
), var1 = c(4, 5, 6
), var2 = c(1, 2, 3
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
df
df_sf <- sf::st_as_sf( df, wkt = "geometry" )
# Simple feature collection with 3 features and 2 fields
# geometry type:  LINESTRING
# dimension:      XY
# bbox:           xmin: -85.89 ymin: 38.31 xmax: -85.42 ymax: 38.76
# CRS:            NA
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#                       geometry  var1  var2
#                   <LINESTRING> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 (-85.76 38.34, -85.72 38.38)     4     1
# 2 (-85.46 38.76, -85.42 38.76)     5     2
# 3 (-85.89 38.31, -85.89 38.31)     6     3
```

We can use `plot` to plot the data including the `LINESTRING` that has two points at the same location (row = 3):

```
plot(st_geometry(df_sf), lwd = 10)
```

giving:

[image]

but when we plot it using `ggplot` the point is dropped:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = df_sf, lwd = 8)
```

[image]

Without manually extracting locations that only contain a point, is there a quick way to tell `ggplot` to plot these? I can see that these points are technically not a line as theres no distance between them but `plot` is able to pick them up. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58400453/cannot-plot-sf-linestring-in-r-error-in-cpl-geos-is-emptyst-geometryx) seems related but slightly different, my `LINESTRING`s are already created.

thanks

Comment: also helpful but doesnt answer why `ggplot` default is not like `plot` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49887283/spatial-line-start-and-end-point-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those situations where the headdesk emoji might come in handy:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = df_sf, lwd = 8, lineend = "round")
```

[image: plot]

From the package's [vignette on aesthetic specs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/ggplot2-specs.html), the default lineend is "butt", which stops precisely at the end point of a line (so a line of 0 length won't have anything to show), while the "round" alternative extends beyond the end point:

[image: illustration]

**TL;DR**: The 0-length linestring wasn't dropped. We just couldn't see it.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, makes you think that `round` should be the default for this particular reason, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can solve that problem if you modify the LINESTRING geometries whose length is equal to 0 and cast them as POINTS. For example:

```r
# packages
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1

# data
df <- structure(
  list(
    geometry = c(
      "LINESTRING (-85.76 38.34, -85.72 38.38)",
      "LINESTRING (-85.46 38.76, -85.42 38.76)", 
      "LINESTRING (-85.89 38.31, -85.89 38.31)"
      ), 
    var1 = c(4, 5, 6), 
    var2 = c(1, 2, 3)
    ), 
  row.names = c(NA, -3L), 
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)
df_sf <- st_as_sf( df, wkt = "geometry" )

# Rebuild the geometry column in such a way that the zero-length LINESTRINGS are
# actually POINTS:
new_df_sf_geometry <- st_geometry(df_sf)
idx <- which(st_length(new_df_sf_geometry) == 0)
for (i in idx) {
  new_df_sf_geometry[i] <- unique(st_cast(new_df_sf_geometry[i], "POINT"))
}

# This is the result
new_df_sf_geometry
#> Geometry set for 3 features 
#> geometry type:  GEOMETRY
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -85.89 ymin: 38.31 xmax: -85.42 ymax: 38.76
#> CRS:            NA
#> LINESTRING (-85.76 38.34, -85.72 38.38)
#> LINESTRING (-85.46 38.76, -85.42 38.76)
#> POINT (-85.89 38.31)

# Replace the geometry
st_geometry(df_sf) <- new_df_sf_geometry

# Plot
ggplot(df_sf) + 
  geom_sf(size = 3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

If you need, you can also adopt more sophisticated approaches than a for-loop such as `purrr::map_if`.

Comment: thanks but I was looking for something that didn't go down this route (I would have thought there would be an option to specify plot points). I think it makes more sense for this to be the default like `plot`? The user would need to know beforehand that there is `LINSTRING` data of length `0` within their dataset which I feel is presumptuous!

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry but I cannot help you further since I don't understand the internals of `ggplot2` or `geom_sf`. Maybe you can create a new issue on [their github page](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2).

Comment: the solution i was after is above...you may be interested